# Is there any way we can only validate field name not value in Pact json

Tags: pact

The example below is the response. In this I just want to validate field not field value from the body.

When I do pact verify:

```
{
  "provider": {
    "name": "provider"
  },
  "consumer": {
    "name": "consumer"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "A valid data read request",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/v1/users",
        "query": {
          "user": [
            "1"
          ]
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "name": "xyz",
          "work": "gen",
          "age": "29",    
        }
      },
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "user exists state"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    },
    "pact-jvm": {
      "version": "4.0.4"
    }
  }
}
```

Only i need to validate field such as name, age and work not field value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    got solution we can achieve this using

final DslPart body = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("name", "xyz")
                .stringType("work", "gen")
                .integerType("age", 29)

or for only optional

     DslPart body = new PactDslJsonBody()
                        .eachKeyLike("name", PactDslJsonRootValue.stringType("xyz"))
                        .eachKeyLike("work", PactDslJsonRootValue.stringType("gen"))
                        .eachKeyLike("age", PactDslJsonRootValue.integerType(29))
                        .asBody()

    and set this body to PactDslWithProvider body and we can have matching rule generated in the json so that when we verify only the field type and field name
```